# Объединение объектов QGraphicItem в единый обьект

Tags: c++, qt

Суть проблемы такова, что не понятно, как можна обьединить несколько производных от QGraphicItem объектов в ед. обьект, над которым будут применяться операции такие же, как и для производного класса?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html)

Comment: Уже пробовал, но безуспешно. Нужен пример. Как говорил Линус Торвальдс :"Болтовня ничего не стоит, покажите нам код".

Comment: Тогда, нужно было приложить к вопросу ваши попытки, а то как говорил Линус Торвальдс :"Болтовня ничего не стоит, покажите нам код" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сцене создается квадрат желтого цвета, на котором расположены две надписи и этот квадрат можно передвигать:

```
class MyGroupItem: public QGraphicsItemGroup {
public:
    MyGroupItem() : QGraphicsItemGroup() {
        setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

        text.setPlainText("!!!");
        text2.setPlainText("@@@");
        text2.setPos(0, 20);

        rect.setRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
        rect.setBrush(Qt::yellow);

        addToGroup(&rect);
        addToGroup(&text);
        addToGroup(&text2);
    }

private:
    QGraphicsTextItem text;
    QGraphicsTextItem text2;
    QGraphicsRectItem rect;
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]